# I have an H264 Bitstream, how can I stream it?

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, intel-video-processing

So, I am currently using the Intel Media SDK to generate a H264 Bitstream, one packet at a time.  I can save that to a file and play the video directly from the file using VLC.

However, I don't know where to get started when it comes to streaming those packets.  I believe I would like to create a server that will stream out this video and then use HTML5's video tag to display receive that video remotely.

Thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<video>` tag does not work with raw elementary streams. The video must be in a container.
 http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp. Also you may find some browsers do not support h.264.

Your use of the word 'stream' seem to imply live video. There is no HTML5 video solution for streaming video (except HLS in safari on mac and IOS). Streaming from a container such as mp4 is called progressive download, or pseudo streaming.

Comment: It is indeed live video.  This is not h264 format but I was able to stream snapshots of the desktop(granted with some lag on one side or the other), to the video tag in html5, so obviously possible, using:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -I dummy screen:// :screen-fps=16.000000 :screen-caching=10 :sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,scale=1,width=640,height=480,acodec=mp3}:http{mux=ogg,dst=192.168.16.48:8084/desktop.ogg} :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=1 :sout-keep

Will look into containers. Thank you.

Comment: Not in internet explorer or safari. They don't support oog.

Comment: Good to know.. chrome allows it but just tried it, and indeed IE does not currently support it and firefox is being glitchy.  I have the video in H264 format any idea how I'd do it?  Doesn't have to use the HTML5 video tag but needs to be displayable in a website.

Comment: For mobile HLS is your best bet. On the web RTMP with a flash player is probably best. Or do HLS everywhere and use jwplayer.

Comment: I am still trying to figure this one out and maybe you know, do you know any tools that would let me take the h264 packets and encode them as preferably HLS?  Thanks again szatmary!

Comment: ffmpeg can create HLS segments from an annex-b input.